Retirement age of lawyers in different countries
What is the retirement age of lawyers in different countries?
Does the retirement age of lawyers  vary from country to country?

Do you have reason to believe it's different from the general retirement age for anyone?

united-states
In the U.S., there is no fixed retirement age for lawyers, although there is one for judges in some federal and state judicial positions. Lawyers retire when they want to do so.
